# OfficeJS add-in EWS on-prem - acquire authentication token on client-side

Tags: office-js, exchangewebservices

Together with the team we are developing an Outlook add-in which main responsibility is saving e-mails from customer's inboxes in our system. We have successfully done this for Exchange Online and covered most of the functionality in Exchange on-premise (2019).
We have however stumbled upon a problem when looking into shared mailboxes in on-premise scenarios.
To fetch both e-mail and attachments' content we are using EWS, but it seems like in shared mailbox scenario the EWS auth token that we receive from OfficeJS is limited in terms of privileges and does not have permissions to fetch any of the mentioned data.

Question is: Is there a way to fetch e-mail and attachment content in any other way than via EWS? Or maybe there is a way to acquire a token that would have full user scope on the client side (add-in)?

We have tested that with full user scope (signed in to EWS on backend with hardcoded user login/pass) we are able to access the data via EWS endpoint just like in regular scenario.

Also, we have been looking for a way to authenticate with full user scope in the add-in, but so far with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the use of Shared Mailboxes from the OfficeJS API, and has nothing to do with Exchange online/prem, as your prem version is very high. Regarding Shared Mailboxes there is the whole article from Microsoft [Enable shared folders and shared mailbox scenarios in an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows%2Cxmlmanifest). This would be useful information to read, please do so, but to answer on your question it would be simple just to look at the section [REST and EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows%2Cxmlmanifest#rest-and-ews) where they are clearly stated: `"EWS isn't supported."`. So if you would like to access Shared Mailboxes content from your add-on, you should look at the REST implementation of the functionality you currently perform with EWS requests.